# is there way to debug or capture javascript errors in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

The scenario is easy - I create PDFs with wkhhtmltopdf, and sometimes I struggle with things like

```
window.performance
```

not supported by this version.

So scripts are not fully executed.

Until now my way to find errors like that, was to use the very old Windows `Safari` browser, that helped me finding these errors.

But now I have a script error with the old wkhtmtlopdf, that does not even show in windows Safari.

I found it (or not really) with heavy and nasty script changing (comment out the half), but I would like to know if there is a way to get the correct error with wkhtmtlopdf while parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run wkhhtmltopdf with the command line using `--debug-javascript` argument.

Comment: How do I setup the cookie/authentication if I have an ASP.NET MVC app? For me, whenever I use the console, it produces a PDF of my login page because it cant' authenticate. I've trying putting the key and the values for my JWT auth token, but no luck :(